# Get first number in comma separated string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following code:

```
Pattern.compile( "^\\d+").matcher("7861,1194,B545,B441,12").find()
```

it returns true,

but

`Pattern.compile( "^\\d+").matcher("7861,1194,B545,B441,12").group(0)`
, throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

What wrong with my regex ?

**P.S.** expexted result `7861`

Comment: You are not calling `find()` :)

Comment: find() before you group

Comment: No match has been attempted. Call `find()` before calling `group()`.

Comment: ooops, I didn't know it

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `matcher.find()` before you can use `.group(0)`

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( "^\\d+").matcher("7861,1194,B545,B441,12");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Comment: This only works as long as the whole expression is the group the OP wants.  OP should define group in expression and get group 1 instead, group 0 is the whole expression.

Comment: @Isthar But it's the whole match that the OP wants, so using `group(0)` or `group()` is appropriate. No need to introduce additional groups that are never used.

Comment: Of course, if all the OP needs, is that single match, a simple `System.out.println("7861,1194,B545,B441,12".replaceFirst("^(\\d+).*", "$1"));` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke `find` on a `Matcher` first before using `group`:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( "^\\d+").matcher("7861,1194,B545,B441,12");
matcher.find();
String num = matcher.group(); // equivalent to group(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to find a group inside the match, you have to define groups with `()` inside your regexp.

```
"^(\\d+)"
```

Beside, the first group is 1 and no 0. Group 0 is the whole expression matched; in your case works because the whole expression is what you want.
And you have to call `find()` before `group()`, but I suppose you are doing it already as you say `find()` works.

This should work:

```
Pattern.compile( "^(\\d+)").matcher("7861,1194,B545,B441,12").group(1)
```

Comment: That’s funny, you say yourself, “*you have to call `find()` before `group()`*” and then present a “This should work” code that fails to do so…